# How to identify the Databases which are accessing a table in my own database in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Example :- I am working on DB_1 database and DB_1 database has table name called Employee. Other Databases i.e DB_2, DB_3 are accessing Employee table in DB_1 database. So how to identify the what are the other databases which are accessing employee table in DB_1 database. Here my expected output is DB_2, DB_3.

Comment: So i am looking for SQL query to identify above expected result.

Comment: When you say other databases, do you mean other schemas within the same instance, or separate instances? Either way, unless you have auditing switched on, I think you will need to query `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` or `v$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` with `V$SQLAREA` to search for who/what is referencing that table.

Comment: Do you mean databases or users? In Oracle, a database contains multiple schemas and each schema belongs to one user, so if a remote database is accessing your tables then you would be looking for sessions connected via a database link.

Answer (score 0):

Check the view

```
select name from v$database;
```

If you are on a RAC database, you can additionaly get the instance number using the view

```
select INSTANCE_NUMBER, INSTANCE_NAME from v$instance;
```

If you get

```
ORA-00942: Tabelle oder View nicht vorhanden
```

as a result, you must ask your DBA to assign those privileges to your user.

```
grant select on sys.v_$database to <your user name>;
grant select on sys.v_$instance to <your user name>;
```

is the `name`you use to connect to the database.